# Oracle SELECT INTO OUTFILE, what's wrong with this query?

Tags: oracle, select, file-io

This is the query that I am executing from sqlplus:

```
select * into outfile 'my_file.txt' 
fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n'
from my_table where my_column = 'stuff';
```

I get the following error:

```
FROM keyword not found where expected
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I know that there are other ways to flush the output to file but I really want to win this against Oracle...

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` is MySQL-specific syntax. It won't work on other DBMSs such as Oracle.

In Oracle you would surround the statement with `SPOOL filename`...`SPOOL OFF`.

Comment: Note that this is a SQL*Plus command and not part of SQL or PLSQL

Comment: No way to win this then... The spool command is a bit of a pain to use, it prints even my query and everything else that I type into the output file. Is there any other way to get the result into a comma/tab separated file?

Comment: If you're happy with writing PL/SQL stored procs, you can write to a file using `UTL_FILE`.